# Solace SDKPerf send text file or string message

Tags: java, solace

I want to send a specific message using `sdkperf` **in Solace**. But I cannot find the cli command for this. Can someone help me?

```
sdkperf_java.bat -cip=<IP> -cu=<user>@<vpn> -cp=<password> -pql=<QUEUE name> -mt=persistent -mn=5 -mr=1 -??="hello"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -pal option if you would like to send a specific message through sdkperf.

You will need to have the message in a file.

The syntax of the -pal option will be as such:

`-pal= <file_location>`